# How do I stub new Date() using sinon?

Tags: javascript, testing, sinon, stub

I want to verify that various date fields were updated properly but I don't want to mess around with predicting when `new Date()` was called. How do I stub out the Date constructor?

```
import sinon = require('sinon');
import should = require('should');

describe('tests', () => {
  var sandbox;
  var now = new Date();

  beforeEach(() => {
    sandbox = sinon.sandbox.create();
  });

  afterEach(() => {
    sandbox.restore();
  });

  var now = new Date();

  it('sets create_date', done => {
    sandbox.stub(Date).returns(now); // does not work

    Widget.create((err, widget) => {
      should.not.exist(err);
      should.exist(widget);
      widget.create_date.should.eql(now);

      done();
    });
  });
});
```

In case it is relevant, these tests are running in a node app and we use TypeScript.

Answer (score 99, accepted):

I *suspect* you want the [`useFakeTimers`](https://sinonjs.org/releases/v6.1.5/fake-timers/) function:

```js
var now = new Date();
var clock = sinon.useFakeTimers(now.getTime());
//assertions
clock.restore();
```

This is plain JS. A working TypeScript/JavaScript example:

```js
var now = new Date();

beforeEach(() => {
    sandbox = sinon.sandbox.create();
    clock = sinon.useFakeTimers(now.getTime());
});

afterEach(() => {
    sandbox.restore();
    clock.restore();
});
```

Comment: Awesome, that looks like it does what I needed. Once I get a finally working version I'll edit it into your answer and accept it.

Comment: As of sinon v5, the `sinon` object is a sandbox which keeps track of the `sinon.useFakeTimers`, which can be invoked with `sinon.restore()`, allowing the `sandbox` and `clock` variables in the above to be dropped: https://sinonjs.org/guides/migrating-to-5.0.html#sinon-is-now-a-default-sandbox

Comment: only a minor observation here: when you use a sandbox (as you should), you don't need to `clock.restore()`, as the sandbox handles it

Answer (score 23):

I found this question when i was looking to solution how to mock `Date` constructor ONLY.
I wanted to use same date on every test but to avoid mocking `setTimeout`.
Sinon is using [lolex][1] internally
Mine solution is to provide object as parameter to sinon:

```
let clock;

before(() => {
    clock = sinon.useFakeTimers({
        now: new Date(2019, 1, 1, 0, 0),
        shouldAdvanceTime: true,
        toFake: ["Date"],
    });
})

after(() => {
    clock.restore();
})
```

Other possible parameters you can find in [lolex][1] API
[1]: https://github.com/sinonjs/lolex#api-reference

Comment: This answer is incredible and shows knowledge about the sinon/lolex API. it should be marked as correct, as it also solves the need of having a lot of `clock.tick()`s around the test.

Answer (score 19):

`sinon.useFakeTimers()` was breaking some of my tests for some reason, I had to stub `Date.now()`

```
sinon.stub(Date, 'now').returns(now);
```

In that case in the code instead of `const now = new Date();` you can do

```
const now = new Date(Date.now());
```

Or consider option of using [moment](https://www.npmjs.com/package/moment) library for date related stuff. Stubbing moment is easy.

Comment: This worked for me except that `Date.now()` returns a timestamp, so I think the `now` method should be stubbed with the timestamp returned by `Date.now()` instead of creating a new Date with `new Date()`. Basically the second line should be: `const now = Date.now();`